# Can Rails be configured to show model attributes in a particular order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

As per [this DBA question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3276/how-can-i-specify-the-position-for-a-new-column-in-postgresql), it is not possible to specify the order of database columns in PostgreSQL except by creating the columns in the right order in the first place.

However, I don't care about the column order in PostgreSQL itself, as the only time I ever look at the columns is in Rails. Is it possible to configure my models in Rails so that they will display their attributes in an order that I prefer when I inspect them with `awesome_print` or when printing `Model.attribute_names`?

Comment: What do you mean by display in order? How will you be printing the attributes in first place?

Comment: Urgh, stupid oversight! Editing now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model.attribute_names` returns an array, and `@model.attributes` returns a hash, both of which are enumerable. That means you can operate on them with methods like `sort`:

```
Model.attribute_names.sort
@model.attributes.sort.to_h
```

If you want them in an arbitrary order you could create a presenter class that inherits from [SimpleDelegator](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html):

```
class ModelPresenter < SimpleDelegator
  def inspect
    {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      # ...
    }
  end
end
```

Then initialize it in your views like:

```
ModelPresenter.new(@model).inspect
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't really order the attributes by setting some option in Rails models, because the implementation of `attribute_names` is:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb, line 271
def attribute_names
  @attributes.keys
end
```

It just returns the keys of the `@attributes` hash, which are the attribute names per se.

What you can do however, is manipulating the method return itself, because it is a simple `Array`, so you can order in anyway way you like.

Link to the documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/attribute_names

Comment: How does it get that hash in the first place?

Comment: Well, you will have to go up and up in the chain of events. It is always good to look at the source code, but it can get kind of complicated. I suggest you open `ActiveRecord` code on github and give it a try.